# A question about the stability of a property of the normal distribution

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions

Recall that the standard normal distribution can be characterized as the unique standardized (having mean zero and unit variance) distribution $P$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with the property that with $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ independent variables with distribution $P$, it holds that $Z$ has the same distribution as $X/\sqrt{2}+Y/\sqrt{2}$. In other words, the normal distribution can be characterized as a standardized 2-stable distribution.

Loosely put, my question is whether this characterization is stable under perturbation, in the following sense:

$\textbf{Question.}$ Consider a standardized distribution $P$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and independent variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ with distribution $P$. If $Z$ almost has the same distribution as $X/\sqrt{2}+Y/\sqrt{2}$, is $P$ almost a normal distribution?

The question can be made more precise in the following manner. Consider a metric $d$ on the space of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$. What are the optimal functions $c$ and $C$ such that

$\qquad c(d(P,\mathcal{N})) \le d(P, t(P)\ast t(P))\le C(d(P,\mathcal{N}))$

where $\mathcal{N}$ denotes the standard normal distribution and $t(x)=x/\sqrt{2}$? Inequalities such as the above would essentially show that if $P$ is close to $2$-stable, then $P$ is close to normal, and vice versa, and would bound the rates at which this "closeness" occurs.

For some perspective, a similar result is known which instead compares what is known as the "components" of a distribution. Let $d_L$ denote the Levy-Prokhorov distance (which metrizes weak convergence). It holds that there is a mapping $\delta(\varepsilon)$ such that if $P = P_1 \ast P_2$ and $d(P,\mathcal{N})\le \varepsilon$, then $d(P_1,\mathcal{N}')\le\delta(\varepsilon)$ and $d(P_1,\mathcal{N}'')\le\delta(\varepsilon)$ for some normal distributions $\mathcal{N}'$ and $\mathcal{N}''$, where $\delta(\varepsilon)$ tends to zero as $\varepsilon$ tends to zero. In other words, for distributions which are close to normal, its components (the $P_1$ and $P_2$ above) must be close to normal as well. Furthermore, the asymptotically optimal rate of $\delta(\varepsilon)$ is known: By a result of Golinskii & Chistyakov (building on many previous results), it holds that the optimal rate is

$\qquad(\log\log 1/\varepsilon)^2/\sqrt{\log 1/\varepsilon}$

as $\varepsilon$ approaches zero.

Comment: Do you know the following result? If $X$, $Y$ are independent random variables such that $X \sim Y$ and $X \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (X+Y)$, then $X \sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks, no I haven't seen that theorem before. Looks like an interesting variation over the characterization of the normal distribution as the alpha-stable distribution of order two. Where did you see this result?

Comment: Rényi, Probability theory, VI.5, Theorem 2 (I don't own the book, but found the reference in another book.)